# How can I spawn my own program in a linux tty-session instead of the shell?

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, systemd

I want to spawn a little TUI program instead of the shell on a raspberry-pi on the standard tty (without x11 of course)

Therefore I need to know how to switch of the starting of the standard-shell there and how to start my own program?

Using Raspbian9 with systemd

Answer (score 3):

In systemd, local virtual consoles are managed by `getty@.service` and serial lines by `serial-getty@.service`. Both start the *agetty* program which initializes a few tty parameters, displays the banner, and the "login:" prompt.

For your program, it's best to just use the existing unit as a base, and change it to run the custom program.

Copy `/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/myapp@.service`. Edit your new file to have the correct program in *ExecStart=*, and additionally add a line `Conflicts=getty@%i.service` in the *[Unit]* section.

Test with `systemctl start myapp@tty1`. If it works, disable the original *getty@tty1.service* through systemctl and enable your own.

Comment: There is no such folder, only  `/usr/lib/systemd/` exists

Comment: Then your distro probably keeps unit files in `/lib/systemd/system/` instead.

Comment: You meant to write `Conflicts=getty@%I.service`, with uppercase 'I', correct?

Thanks for the great advice so far, this seems to be the right way, but when I try to start my service everything except a blinking underscore in tty1 disappears