# Single button reboot on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, reboot

I am running Linux mint 19, mate version on an augmented reality sandbox.  The computer runs a Kinect camera, and a projector, and displays a topographic incline of the sand surface in a box below the camera.  Attached to this is a four button USB device that has two buttons assigned to control functions in the sandbox operating code.  The system occasionally crashes, which I am troubleshooting.  In the meantime, I am hoping to assign one of the remaining buttons to reboot the system when the program crashes.

The USB device is an iKKGOL 4 Key user defined keyboard. The actual computer running this device is locked in a podium, so I am trying to make it that users can restart the system when it crashes.

Digging around, I can find the keyboard shortcuts tool. I name the tool reboot, then in the command, I type sudo reboot. I can then assign a button to this command. However, the 4 button key pad is identified as a, b, c, d. If I assign "d" to the command, the computer tells me that I cannot do this, as I won't be able to type anymore. So ideally, I would need to change the value of the key on the 4 button keyboard to another value that would be useable.

Playing around more, I have found the software to reprogram the USB buttons. I tried programming f9 to the one button, and it recognized it. I then built a keyboard shortcut in Linux, and assigned that button, and F9 showed up in the dialog. However, it is not rebooting.

So now all I need is help to troubleshoot why the reboot command will not work when I press the button.

Comment: You might want to include what type of USB device you are using.

Comment: Would it be an option to assign the power button to reboot?

Comment: Could you please run `xev`, press the key in question and edit your question with the output to identify the key without and doubt?

Comment: We also need to know which exact software you use to assign the shortcuts to find a solution.

Comment: It might be possible that you'll need root permissions to run reboot on your system. You could edit `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo` so that you don't need a password for `reboot` as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85665/454022)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `/dev/input/by-path`, you should find a symlink for your USB four-button device. Run `evtest` on that symlink, you should see keyboard events when you press the buttons.

Find some tool that can launch programs on input layer events. For example, [lirc](https://superuser.com/a/1422570/327880) works for this, there are also smaller ones you need to self-install, e.g. [inputexec](https://github.com/rbarrois/inputexec). Google for more choices. Configure chosen tool to execute "reboot". Make sure you run it as a user with permissions for that. Debug by making it execute something else that doesn't need root permissions.

This will only listen for events from that particular device, so it doesn't matter if the buttons produce "normal" keys.

I have no idea what "keyboard shortcuts tool" you are talking about, as you didn't identify it. It may or may not be able to do what you want.